# Flexbox layout, stumped on the header section

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Curious if you flexbox gurus out there have a moment to help on this layout (and open to also using Grid if it is necessary for this, but I think it should be achievable with flexbox).

All those years of bootstrap have conditioned my brain and I need to retrain it.

Here is what I have thus far, still messing with it.

What I have:
The logo is placed and the stats part is pulled to the right, but I cannot figure out how to put that into columns properly.

Desired Result

[image]

```
<mat-toolbar>
  <div class="company-logo"></div>
  <div class="stats">
    <div class="stats-one">
      Info 1: XXX
      Info 2: XXX
    </div>
    <mat-divider [vertical]="true"></mat-divider>
    <div>
      Info 3: XXX
      Info 4: XXX
    </div>
  </div>
</mat-toolbar>
```

```
.mat-toolbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 5em;
  background-color: #4CAEB2;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.company-logo {
  align-self: flex-end;
  background-image: url("../../../assets/images/logo.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 4em;
  flex-basis: 20em;
}

.stats {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: auto;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox *can* deliver the layout, but it would require excessive code in my view.

A more efficient solution would use both flexbox and grid.

I've posted an example below.

Each line of code performs a specific function. To see what each rule does go into Dev Tools and toggle the checkmark for each one.

```css
mat-toolbar {
  display: flex;
  height: 5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.company-logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.stats {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.stats-one {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.stats-one::before {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  content: '';
  height: 80%;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<mat-toolbar>
  <div class="company-logo">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="65" height="65" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="stats">
    <div class="stats-one">
      <div>Info 1: XXX</div>
      <div>Info 2: XXX</div>
      <div>Info 3: XXX</div>
      <div>Info 4: XXX</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</mat-toolbar>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lzh321j/1/)

Comment: Thank you. that put me on the right track. Much appreciated!